# MS SQL 2012 - How can I insert timestamps for continuation of a time series chart?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement that calculates how many parts per minute are processed. The problem is if no parts are processed in that minute I don't have a record of 0 for that time. This means I don't know that a process is stopped until another part is created.

Statement:

```
SELECT convert(datetime,FORMAT(dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00:000')) as dt
,count(*) as ppm
  FROM tblx group by FORMAT(dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00:000')
```

What I have(not times 10:59 to 11:02):

```
+-------------------------+-----+
|           dt            | ppm |
+-------------------------+-----+
| 2020-07-06 10:55:00.000 | 177 |
| 2020-07-06 10:56:00.000 | 176 |
| 2020-07-06 10:57:00.000 | 177 |
| 2020-07-06 10:58:00.000 |  36 |
| 2020-07-06 11:03:00.000 |  70 |
| 2020-07-06 11:04:00.000 |  92 |
| 2020-07-06 11:07:00.000 |  54 |
| 2020-07-06 11:08:00.000 | 153 |
+-------------------------+-----+
```

What I'm trying to generate:

```
+-------------------------+-----+
|           dt            | hbh |
+-------------------------+-----+
| 2020-07-06 10:55:00.000 | 177 |
| 2020-07-06 10:56:00.000 | 176 |
| 2020-07-06 10:57:00.000 | 177 |
| 2020-07-06 10:58:00.000 |  36 |
| 2020-07-06 10:59:00.000 |   0 |
| 2020-07-06 10:00:00.000 |   0 |
| 2020-07-06 10:01:00.000 |   0 |
| 2020-07-06 10:02:00.000 |   0 |
| 2020-07-06 11:03:00.000 |  70 |
| 2020-07-06 11:04:00.000 |  92 |
| 2020-07-06 11:07:00.000 |  54 |
| 2020-07-06 11:08:00.000 | 153 |
+-------------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a recursive CTE to create a table in your script that has the datetimes you want with the required granularity.

For example this script can generate a table with a row for each minute in a day:

```
    WITH numbers AS
    (
        SELECT 0 num
        UNION ALL
        SELECT num + 1 FROM numbers WHERE num <= 58
    )
    SELECT
        NN.num AS Hour
        , AA.num AS Minute
        , CAST(IIF(NN.num < 10, '0'+CAST(NN.Num AS CHAR(1)), CAST(NN.Num AS CHAR(2)))
        + ':' + IIF(AA.num < 10, '0'+CAST(AA.Num AS CHAR(1)), CAST(AA.Num AS CHAR(2))) AS TIME(0)) Time
    INTO
        #time_table
    FROM
        numbers NN
        LEFT JOIN
            numbers AA ON
                1 = 1
    WHERE
        NN.num <= 23
```

You could get all the dates from your data, join the dates to the times generated by the above script then left join back onto your data. Then fill in the NULLs with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Tim O'Sullivan sugjested, I created this table, then joined to the original dateset.

```
WITH   cte
AS     (--SELECT getdate() - 2 AS n -- anchor member
        SELECT convert(datetime,FORMAT(getdate() -2, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00:000')) as n
        UNION ALL
        SELECT dateadd(mi, 1, n) -- recursive member
        FROM   cte
        WHERE  n < getdate() -- terminator
       )
SELECT n
FROM   cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5000)
```

Comment: Then you should give Tim the appropriate credit and mark his response as the answer.